# Unresponsive script error when viewing the reputation tab in profile

Tags: bug, status-completed, profile-page, reputation-history

I get an unresponsive script error in Windows 7/IE8 when clicking the reputation tab in the profile on both SO and Meta.  No problems in FF.   Using developer tools to clear the browser cache did not resolve the problem.

[image: unresponsive script error]

Comment: I get the same thing. I've tried clicking "No" several times but it never finishes.

Comment: ......Show off.

Comment: This is a deliberate ploy by SO to limit your rep. Please start over with another identity. You can suggest edits to aid your rep (re)building this time around.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rep view is now paged so this shouldn't be an issue any longer, even in older browsers.

*Update:* This is now live across the network.